# Select with subtotals using postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, subtotal

I've the following query:

```
select
    json_build_object('id', i.id, 'task_id', i.task_id, 'time_spent', i.summary)
from
    intervals I
where
    extract(month from "created_at") = 10 
    and extract(year from "created_at") = 2021
group by
    i.id, i.task_id
order by i.task_id
```

Which gives the following output:

> | json_build_object |
> | --- |
> | {"id" : 53, "task_id" : 1, "time_spent" : "3373475"} |
> | {"id" : 40, "task_id" : 1, "time_spent" : "3269108"} |
> | {"id" : 60, "task_id" : 2, "time_spent" : "2904084"} |
> | {"id" : 45, "task_id" : 4, "time_spent" : "1994341"} |
> | {"id" : 38, "task_id" : 5, "time_spent" : "1933766"} |
> | {"id" : 62, "task_id" : 5, "time_spent" : "2395378"} |
> | {"id" : 44, "task_id" : 6, "time_spent" : "3304280"} |
> | {"id" : 58, "task_id" : 6, "time_spent" : "3222501"} |
> | {"id" : 48, "task_id" : 6, "time_spent" : "1990195"} |
> | {"id" : 55, "task_id" : 7, "time_spent" : "1984300"} |

How can I add subtotals of `time_spent` by each task?

I'd like to have an array structure of objects like this:

```
{
    "total": 3968600,
    "details:" [
        {"id" : 55, "task_id" : 7, "time_spent" : "1984300"}, 
        {"id" : 55, "task_id" : 7, "time_spent" : "1984300"}
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following modification which groups your data based on the `task_id` and uses [`json_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) and [`json_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) to produce your desired schema.

```sql
select
    json_build_object(
        'total', SUM(i.summary),
        'details',json_agg(
            json_build_object(
                'id', i.id, 
                'task_id', i.task_id, 
                'time_spent', i.summary
             )
         )
      ) as result
from
    intervals I
where
    extract(month from "created_at") = 10 
    and extract(year from "created_at") = 2021
group by
    i.task_id
order by i.task_id
```

See working demo fiddle online [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vcndBtmTVTtUiuRXYpPMJY/0)

Comment: it did the trick, thank you very much!